# T-SQL: formatting "numeric" to format similar to c# style {0:#.00####}

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an easy way to format SQL Server **numeric(18,6)** data type to format similar to c#'s **{0:#.00####}** but in T-SQL?

E.g.

1. 12.550000 should produce 12.55.
2. 14.456700 should produce 14.4567.
3. 15.00 should produce 15.00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As HLGEM says, it's best to do this kind of stuff on the front end, but for kicks, the following code seems to work. There's probably a better way to do it though.

```
REPLACE(
     RTRIM(
          REPLACE(
               CAST(@test AS VARCHAR), '0', ' '
          )
     ), ' ', '0'
) +
CASE
     WHEN @test = FLOOR(@test) THEN '00'
     WHEN FLOOR(@test*10) = @test * 10 THEN '0'
     ELSE ''
END
```

Comment: Small correction:

WHEN @test = FLOOR(@test) THEN '.00'

should be 
... THEN '00'

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected that. In its initial incarnation the decimal was necessary, but it's not now.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly that type of formatting is best done by the application not in the SQL. SQl is for data access and for affecting the content of the data, it is not really good at any formatting.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit different case without trailing '.00':

```
CAST(CAST(@val AS REAL) AS VARCHAR)
```

1. 12.550000 will produce 12.55.
2. 14.456700 will produce 14.4567.
3. 15.00 will produce 15.

Answer (score 1):

To format values ​​without the need for Cast and Substring

use the function Call `Format`

Example:

```
SELECT FORMAT(123456789, '##-##-#####');
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011';  
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result'  
,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-gb' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'de-de' ) AS 'German Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'zh-cn' ) AS 'Simplified Chinese (PRC) Result';
SELECT FORMAT(@d, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS FechaInicial 
SELECT FORMAT(@d, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS FechaInicial 
declare @EndOfDayRate as decimal(18,4)='1.0002' 
SELECT  @EndOfDayRate   as EndOfDayRate
            ,FORMAT(@EndOfDayRate, 'N', 'en-us') AS 'Number Format'  
            ,FORMAT(@EndOfDayRate, 'G', 'en-us') AS 'General Format'  
            ,FORMAT(@EndOfDayRate, 'C', 'en-us') AS 'Currency Format'*
```

Copy and paste the code and run it on SQL server

For more information in the official documentation of SQL server: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: This is the only right answer, but the OP no longer has a StackOverflow account so I don't know if mods can change this to the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [CONVERT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and [CAST()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) functions

```
SELECT CAST(@val AS numeric(18,6))

SELECT CAST(@val AS decimal(18,6))
```

I haven't come across a native T-SQL format string, but for 2005 onwards, I'm sure you could implement something with CLR UDF's written in .NET language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the instruction "Format" with appropriate label "#.00" to indicate the number of decimal places

```
declare @value1 as numeric(10,8)=12.550000;-- will produce 12.55.
declare @value2 as numeric(10,8)=14.456700; --will produce 14.4567.
declare @value3 as numeric(10,8)=15.00;--will produce 15.

select @value1,@value2,@value3,FORMAT (@value1, '#.00') ,FORMAT (@value1, '#.00'),FORMAT (@value2, '#.00'),FORMAT (@value3, '#.00')
```

[image: result]